# UIPopoverPresentationController : multiple permittedArrowDirections order priority

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

Using `UIPopoverPresentationController` to present a view controller in a popup, you can define `permittedArrowDirections` property to restrict the popup positioning possibilities. We can define multiple directions using `|` operator :

```
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
```

I know that the controller will automatically choose one the those directions, according to available space.

**But is it possible to define order priority ?** In that way : if there is enough space for both directions ***A*** and ***B***, use ***A*** in priority.

I've tried to reverse the order of `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` and `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp`, but it seems to always prioritize on `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown`.

Does anybody has an idea to achieve this ?

Comment: No, it's simply a flag indicating the directions you permit.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. But any way to achieve the desire behavior ?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, no.

Comment: @rmaddy But I mean even not using permittedArrowDirections property…

Comment: You could do you own determination of the best arrow direction and then set just that one direction.

Comment: @rmaddy Understood, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, the `permittedArrowDirections` is a `OptionSet` which is a `bitmask` under the hood. I would recommend you to some math to calculate is there enough space to display on top and pass in one value based on that.

Comment: I was hoping there were an easier solution than calculating, but as others and you suggest, it doesn't seem to be the case. If nobody provides another solution I'll go with this solution :)

Comment: The math should not be that hard, basically you should know the `preferredContentSize` for your popover, and you add the size for the arrow (which is a constant value if you use the default popoverPresentationVC) and you can use the center point of your source view to check if the `y` would be good enough to show up/down, and `x` to show left/right